# Is there a full analysis/explanation of the newspapers available?

Tags: untagged

We are playing through Carlton House at the moment, and we are feeling like we are missing a ton of hidden clues and Easter eggs in the newspapers. Has anyone done a full analysis of these, and where could we read it?